# Open Source Office on Windows Tablet

Tags: windows, open-source, office

I want to view and edit Office files (doc, docx, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx) on my Windows 8 HP **Tablet**.

Is there a free opensource option available that lets me do so? Or any app?

Comment: Except that OP here didn't state it has to work offline (nor does the other one state "Windows" as requirement). So, related: yes. Duplicate: not exactly.

Comment: Yes I need to work offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Libre office](https://www.libreoffice.org/) will let you do this.

---

From  https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Using_Microsoft_Office_and

> LibreOffice can open and save documents in the Microsoft Office file
>   formats, including Microsoft Office Open XML formats.
>
> Contents
>
> ```
> 1 Opening a Microsoft Office File
> 2 Saving as a Microsoft Office File
> 3 Saving Documents by Default in Microsoft Office Formats
> 4 Converting Many Microsoft Office Files into OpenDocument Format
> 5 Macros in Microsoft Office and LibreOffice
>     5.1 You can choose to preserve or delete VBA macros
> ```
>
> Opening a Microsoft Office File
>
> ```
> Choose File - Open. Select a Microsoft Office file in the LibreOffice file open dialog.
> ```
>
> MS Office file...     ...will open in LibreOffice module MS Word, *.doc,
>   *.docx    LibreOffice Writer MS Excel, *.xls, *.xlsx  LibreOffice Calc MS PowerPoint, *.ppt, *.pps, *.pptx    LibreOffice Impress Saving as a
>   Microsoft Office File
>
> ```
> Choose File - Save As.
> In the File type box, select a Microsoft Office file format.
> ```
>
> Saving Documents by Default in Microsoft Office Formats
>
> ```
> Choose Tools - Options - Load/Save - General.
> In the Default file format and ODF settings area, first select a document type, then select the file type for saving.
> ```
>
> From now on, if you save a document, the File type will be set
>   according to your choice. Of course, you still can select another file
>   type in the file save dialog. Converting Many Microsoft Office Files
>   into OpenDocument Format
>
> The Document Converter Wizard will copy and convert all Microsoft
>   Office files in a folder into LibreOffice documents in the
>   OpenDocument file format. You can specify the folder to be read, and
>   the folder where the converted files are to be saved.
>
> ```
> Choose File - Wizards - Document Converter to start the wizard.
> ```
>
> Macros in Microsoft Office and LibreOffice
>
> With a few exceptions, Microsoft Office and LibreOffice cannot run the
>   same macro code. Microsoft Office uses VBA (Visual Basic for
>   Applications) code, and LibreOffice uses Basic code based on the
>   LibreOffice API (Application Program Interface) environment. Although
>   the programming language is the same, the objects and methods are
>   different. Note.png   The most recent versions of LibreOffice can run
>   some Excel Visual Basic scripts if you enable this feature at
>   LibreOffice - PreferencesTools - Options - Load/Save - VBA Properties.
>
> If you use macros in one of the applications and want to use the same
>   functionality in the other application, you must edit the macros.
>   LibreOffice can load the macros that are contained within Microsoft
>   Office files and you can then view and edit the macro code in the
>   LibreOffice Basic IDE editor. You can choose to preserve or delete VBA
>   macros
>
> Open a Microsoft Office document that contains VBA macro code. Change
>   only the normal contents (text, cells, graphics), and do not edit the
>   macros. Save the document as a Microsoft Office file type. Open the
>   file in Microsoft Office, and the VBA macros will run as before.
>
> You may delete the VBA macros from the Microsoft Office file on
>   loading or on saving.

Comment: Now it's a +1 :) Additional info (Mawg was faster with his answer): I'm using LibreOffice for years. Document exchange for the manuscripts of my books with my publisher works via MS Office formats, no complaints. So I can recommend it personally, and thus add the "personal experience" component to this answer :)

Comment: I must admit that I have, in years gone by, had problems with some very obscure stuff, like using superscipting, but only in foot-notes. And that was 5 or more years ago with Open Office.  Comparability keeps getting better - especially, obviously, with XML based file formats. There may still be some obscure, very complicated, spreadsheet formula that might give trouble, but in general, if don't do anything too demanding, or obscure, I would say that there is 100% compatability.

Comment: What I lately have issues with strangely is exporting to RTF (simply hangs). I rarely work with anything but text documents, and that seems to work fine (as outlined above).

Comment: @Mawg My requirement is for a tablet. Does Libre work on a HP Windows 8 Tablet?

Comment: Yes, it does. It works on Windows XXX, tablet or not. Suck it & see ;-) You’ll like it - or your money back

Comment: @Mawg I want to personally thank you for your recommendation. I tried it on my tablet and it worked very well. You just saved me and all those who read this thread, some money ;)

Comment: @Izzy Thank you for sharing your experience! It helped me to try it out myself.

Comment: @IWantToLearn  Glad to hear that - spread the word !